# Using HTMLAgilityPack to get all the values of a select element

Tags: c#, winforms, html-agility-pack

Here is what I have so far:

```cs
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument ht = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();

TextReader reader = File.OpenText(@"C:\Users\TheGateKeeper\Desktop\New folder\html.txt");
ht.Load(reader);

reader.Close();

HtmlNode select= ht.GetElementbyId("cats[]");

List<HtmlNode> options = new List<HtmlNode>();

foreach (HtmlNode option in select.ChildNodes)
{
    if (option.Name == "option")
    {
        options.Add(option);
    }
}
```

Now I have a list of all the "options" for the select element. What properties do I need to access to get the key and the text?

So if for example the html for one option would be:

```html
<option class="level-1" value="1">Funky Town</option>
```

I want to get as output:

```
1 - Funky Town
```

Thanks

Edit: I just noticed something. When I got the child elements of the "Select" elements, it returned elements of type "option" and elements of type "#text".

Hmmm .. #text has the string I want, but select has the value.

I tought HTMLAgilityPack was an html parser? Why did it give me confusing values like this?

Comment: can you post some of the html from the source file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the default configuration for the html parser; it has configured the `<option>` as HtmlElementFlag.Empty (with the comment 'they sometimes contain, and sometimes they don't...'). The `<form>` tag has the same setup (CanOverlap + Empty) which causes them to appear as empty nodes in the dom, without any child nodes.

You need to remove that flag before parsing the document.

```
HtmlNode.ElementsFlags.Remove("option");
```

Notice that the ElementsFlags property is static and any changes will affect all further parsing.

Answer (score 0):

edit: you should probably be selecting the `option` nodes directly via xpath. I think this should work for that:

```
var options = select.SelectNodes("option");
```

that will get your options without the text nodes. the options should contain that string you want somewhere. waiting for your html sample.

```
foreach (var option in options)
{
    int value = int.Parse(option.Attributes["value"].Value);
    string text = option.InnerText;
}
```

you can add some sanity checking on the attribute to make sure it exists.

Comment: That's what I tought too but the innerText for each item is "".

Comment: hmm, i'm using InnerText and it works for me. Maybe look at the `option.FirstChild` and see if that exists/contains your value.